# Swift - Init fatal error

Tags: ios, function, swift, initialization

I am trying initialise values by using functions of `calculate` and `calculateBoundary` in `ViewController2`. I got an run time error, shown in the image below.

**ViewController1**

User inputs values of forces, spring stiffnesses and spring number which are then passed into `forceView2`, `stiffView2` and `springNumView2`, by `prepareforsegue`.

**2 public Functions**

```
public func calculate (f:[Float], s:[Float], n:NSInteger) -> [Float]

public func calculateBoundary (inout f:[Float], s:[Float], n:NSInteger) -> (forceBound1:Float, forceBound2: Float, displacement:[Float])
```

**ViewController2**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableview2: UITableView!

    var forceView2 = [Float]()
    var stiffView2 = [Float]()
    var springNumView2 : NSInteger = NSInteger()

    var forceB1 : Float
    var forceB2 : Float
    var SpringD : [Float]
```

override init () {

```
        if(isCheckedGlobal) {                          
            (forceB1,forceB2,SpringD) = calculateBoundary(&forceView2, stiffView2, springNumView2) }

        else {                        
        SpringD = calculate(forceView2, stiffView2, springNumView2)
        self.forceB1  = forceView2[0]
        self.forceB2 = 0.0 }

        super.init() 
    }

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

[image: Run time error]

Comment: You should never do a comparison if boolType == true is redundant

Comment: If you need the opposite comparison just add ! In front of it: If !boolType {...}

Comment: It can be compiled without the comparison now.

Comment: But why the code doesn't work when i compared just now?

Comment: Also, the Xcode wants me to add the last 2 lines, in order for it to compile. When i run it, my program gives me the return message of the fatal error. which i do not know why...

Comment: Just added it in above.

Comment: try posting a screenshot what line are you getting this fatal error?

Comment: Just uploaded the image of the fatal error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71639/discussion-between-cherry-thia-and-leonardo-savio-dabus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required init is missing, put it below your outlets:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { 
    super.init(coder: aDecoder) 
}
```

You should never do a comparison if boolType == true is redundant.

```
If isCheckedGlobal {...}
```

If you need the opposite comparison just add ! In front of it:

```
If !isCheckedGlobal {...} 

if isCheckedGlobal {
     (forceB1,forceB2,springD) = calculateBoundary(&forceView2, stiffView2, springNumView2)
} else {
    springD = calculate(forceView2, stiffView2, springNumView2)
    forceB1  = forceView2[0]
    forceB2 = 0.0
}
```